# React Native FlatList rendering only 1 object

Tags: arrays, object, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have been struggling with rendering this object in a FlatList. Please can someone help me. There's 2 objects in the FlatList but it is only rendering 1 object for some reason

The `peopleArray`

```
Const peopleArray = [
          "id": "U1600078348291",
          "People": [
            {
              "number": "4",
              "value": "Jack Sparrow",
            },
            {
              "number": "6",
              "value": "Daniel Roberts",
            },
          ],
        ]
```

I have tried the following things and it isn't working

**First Try**

```
<FlatList
      data={Object.keys(obj)}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.index}
 />
```

**Second Try**

```
FlatList
      data={peopleArray}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      renderItem={({item})=><Text>{item.index.key.value}</Text>}
/>
```

**Third Try**
This works but only shows one out of the two objects

```
<FlatList
      data={peopleArray}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      renderItem={({item})=>{<Text>{item[index].value}</Text>}}
/>
```

**Fourth Try**

```
<FlatList
      data={peopleArray}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      renderItem={({item})=>{<Text>{item.value}</Text>}}
/>
```

My Code:

```
const People = (props) => {
  const peopleArray = props.navigation.getParam('people')
  const renderPeople = ({item}) => {
    return <Text>{item[index].value}</Text>
  };
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={peopleArray}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      renderItem={renderPeople}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: You need to directly pass the array to your `FlatList`, so probably something like `data={shoppingList.People}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to "My Code" section you want the list to be created out of "People".
your *FlatList* should look something like this:

```
<FlatList
     data={peopleArray}
     keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
     renderItem={renderPeople}
 />
```

And *renderPeople* like this:

```
const renderPeople = ({item}) => (
           <View>
               {
                 item.People.map(person => <Text>{person.value}</Text>)
               }
           </View>
)
```

Comment: show the whole page and i will let you how to make it work

Comment: you set in flatlist data 'shoppingList'. I don't see variable called 'shoppingList' in code so it can't be all

Comment: Hi that was my mistake I put the proper `data` value which it was supposed to be

Comment: I don't see 'peopleArray' either

Comment: It was already there I just made it clearer . Go check it out now . Thanks

Comment: Assuming peopleArray is an array of object and not as you wrote I edited my answer. try it now